# Android Studio 1.5 - tree view

Tags: android, view, tree

Is it possible to display all packages as a tree in Android Studio?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Its possible to list the packages in Android studio by going to Tools->Windows->Project Structure once the window is showing, click the drop down on the show to Show Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the tree view follow below link and select Project View from the dropdown

[Android Studio Project View](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-androidview.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is possible to display all packages as a tree in Android Studio

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Really great answer! )